# Single Date filter to filter multiple date columns and metrics on the report- In power BI

Tags: date, filtering, multiple-columns

My dataset consists of 9 date columns. I need to define date filter that will filter individual column and pull the records based on date range filtered.

Ex: If date filter is set to last 1 month; any date column having the date falling in last 1 month category shall display the results. Based on date filter; metrics on the report page shall filter accordingly.

Below is the data: For last 1 month as per the below data; Task 5; task 9; task 10 records shall show and total task metric shall be 3.

I have tried appending and merging; it didn't work. Unpivot column does work for some reason and my data source is Sharepoint.

[image]